# SQL Multiple NOT LIKE From DB data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-like

Having the following 2 tables:
tableA

- id
- Name

tableB

- id
- filter

filter is something in the following format: aaa;bbb;ccc;...

and what I need to do is:

```
Select Name
FROM tableA A INNER JOIN
     tableB B
     ON A.id=B.id
WHERE A.Name NOT LIKE aaa AND A.Name NOT LIKE bbb AND A.Name NOT LIKE ccc ...
```

How can I get dynamically the query for doing the NOT LIKE ANDs from the respectively filter row in tableB?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would make your question much clearer.

Comment: Since ithe problem seems to be that b.filter isn't suitable as like expression, you could write a stored function that a) makes a valid like expression of b.filter or b) returns simply true or false when called with A.name and b.filter. And Please make clear if aaa;bbb;ccc is ONE row or three rows..

Comment: The problem is there is no way to make this as a valid expression to use with only one Like, this needs to be applied to multiple Likes

Answer (score 1):

> How can I get dynamically the query for doing the NOT LIKE ANDs from the respectively filter row in tableB?

You can just use the filter with `NOT LIKE`:

```
Select Name
FROM tableA A INNER JOIN
     tableB B
     ON A.id = B.id
WHERE A.Name NOT LIKE b.filter;
```

If you want names where *no filter* matches, then you can use:

```
select a.name
from tableA a
where not exists (select 1
                  from tableB b
                  where A.Name like b.filter
                 );
```

Comment: b.filter is not 1 keyword! b.filter contains multiple keywords separated by ;

Comment: @Idilio . . . This answers the question that you asked here.  I would suggest that you ask a *new* question, with sample data and desired results, if you failed to ask the correct question the first time.

Comment: @Idilio That's a really bad design. Be that as it may, you can just split it with `CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(...)`

Comment: @Charlieface how can the CROSS APPLY help to make the multiple AND NOT LIKE?
By the way what wold be the good design to perform something like this?

Comment: @Idilio . . . You should ask a *new* question, with correct sample data and desired results.  Editing this question is rude, because it invalidates answers.  And providing details in comments is not good.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
Select Name
FROM tableA A INNER JOIN
     tableB B
     ON A.id=B.id
WHERE A.Name LIKE '%^[aaa,bbb,ccc,...]%'
```

Comment: aaa,bbb,ccc,... are independent keywords
as in your query it will look for all together...

Answer (score 0):

**Your table design isn't very good. Ideally you would store each filter in `TableB` in a separate row.**

Be that as it may, you can split the filters with `STRING_SPLIT` and then filter on that:

```sql
SELECT Name
FROM tableA A INNER JOIN
     tableB B
     ON A.id=B.id
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(B.filter, ';') s
    WHERE A.Name LIKE s.value
)
```